# Get categories of a newly saved post inside the save_post hook

Tags: wordpress

I have a `post_save` hook that manages setting the title of a particular post type. Within that logic I need to retrieve the post's categories. However, the categories are not yet saved at the time the `post_save` triggers for the first save of a new post.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_report');
function save_report($post_id) {
    $data = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    if($data['post_type'] == 'report') {
        $date = get_post_meta($post_id)['date'][0];
        // I need to get the category of the post on the first time the post is saved
        // $categories only gets a value AFTER the first save
        $categories = get_the_terms($post_id, 'report_type');
        $cat_string = '';
        foreach($categories as $value) {
            $cat_string .= $value->slug;
        }
        $new_title = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)).' '.$cat_string;
        remove_action('save_post', 'save_report');
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title
        ));
        add_action('save_post', 'save_report');
    }
}
```

Because of this, I have to save the post twice to get it to change the title to what I want. Is it possible to get the new category of the post as it is being saved like this?

Comment: This might solve your problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359706/how-can-you-receive-the-most-recent-permalink-or-terms-of-the-newly-saved-post/359735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're using the categories for after the fact, but you can just retrieve them after the wp_update_post runs.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_report');
function save_report($post_id) {
    $data = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    if($data['post_type'] == 'report') {
        $date = get_post_meta($post_id)['date'][0];

        $new_title = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)).' '.$cat_string;

        remove_action('save_post', 'save_report');

        /* 
         *  return the updated post ID (which is the same really as your 
         *  initial ID, so you could just use that.  But for demonstration it helps 
         *  to see it logically.) 
         */

        $updated_post_id = wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title
        ));

        $categories = get_the_terms($updated_post_id, 'report_type');
        $cat_string = '';
        foreach($categories as $value) {
            $cat_string .= $value->slug;
        }

        add_action('save_post', 'save_report');
    }
}
```

An alternative, if you're both creating and updating posts programatically is to use wp_insert_post, which covers both new creation (if you don't pass an ID), and updating (if you do pass an ID).

You could also create a separate function to retrieve IDs that you could use with any number of other functions you run.

```
function retrieve_report_cats($post_id) {

    cats_list = array();

    $categories = get_the_terms($post_id, 'report_type');

    foreach($categories as $value) {

       $cat = $value->slug;
       $cats_list[] = $cat;

    }

    return $cats_list;

}
```

Comment: Oh man, after many hours working on getting the categories of wpadverts plugin, your function retrieve_report_cats has worked for me. Thanks a lot!